# Ubuntu/presta - PHP's white screen of death

Tags: php

I installed LAMP from scratch on Amazon EC2:
 Apache/2.4.7, PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17, mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.49

I use prestashop (1.4.1.5) but when I run it I get a white screen.

No error in the log or on screen.

I tried to find the line where it breaks and found that if I do:

```
    if (!Language::getLanguage((int)$this->id_lang)) {
        $t =  Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
        echo 1;
        $this->id_lang = $t;
        echo 1;
    }
```

on /classes/Cookie.php line: 277

Only the first '1' is echoed.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: in the console run `sudo php5enmod mcrypt`

Long answer:

The cookie.php file has a

```
    /**
      * Magic method wich add data into _content array
      *
      * @param $key key desired
      * @param $value value corresponding to the key
      */
    public function __set($key, $value)
```

which is executed when doing: `$this->id_lang = ???`, this function is calling some other function that use the encrypt() function.

If u didn't do `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` it will crash the php silently and waist half a work day.

Answer (score -1):

You need a `;` in this line:

```
$this->id_lang = $t
```

So:

```
$this->id_lang = $t;
```

Comment: 10x, but that was just a syntax error in the question and not the actual problem in the code - fixed